# How to set the environment " ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH"?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, windows-10, environment-variables, cx-oracle

Using cx_Oracle to fetch tables with ROWID ends up crashing the python. I read that the solution was to set the environemtn variable 'ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH' to 1. But using os.environ (in python) or Get-ChildItem Env: (in powershell), I don't see this particular variable. Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can also set it in Python itself as in the following:

```
import os

os.environ["ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH"] = "1"
```

Just make sure you do it before you connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

> Then what should I do?

Create it. `$env:ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH = 1` in PowerShell, just before you run Python in the same shell.